# How to make the button not hidden by keyboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, button, keyboard, flutter-layout

I have an app that has multiple textfields and a button that analyze the data entered.
When I fill the textfields, the keyboard pops up and hide the button.
I want the app to slide up completely away from the keyboard.

FYI: `resizeToAvoidBottomInset` is set to `true`, and the main column is wrapped in `singlechildview`.

[Button shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FAuu6.png)
[Button hidden by keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQO2N.png)

Comment: can you provide more code or snippets of your code for better understanding? or You can try reverse: true, ==> this singlechildscrollview's property.

Comment: Also, you can refer this video to clear your doubts about singlechildscrollview ==> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voARoVV_EDI

Comment: LOL, I just looked and found reverse: true solved the issue and came back to update my answer and found the same answer! If you want, you can added as an answer and not as a comment so I can flag it as a best answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this Property in `SinglechildScrollview`:

```
reverse: true
```

It will solve your problem.